# Fatal Errors Template Tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on an old WordPress site. Although the site is updated to the latest version of WordPress (5.9.1) it was apparently built on the twentyfouteeen theme.

Just lately, I am getting a fatal error on the Posts Page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentyfourteen_categorized_blog()
```

The function is located in the `template-tags.php` file and it exists so the theme should be able to access it. In fact, I'm getting the fatal error on any page that calls a twentyfourteen function.

I copied the functions from template-tags.php to content.php which did in fact load posts but then gave me a different error `Cannot redeclare twentyfourteen_categorized_blog()`

I've never had to troubleshoot this kind of error and since the theme is old, I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: _"The function is located in the template-tags.php file and it exists so the theme should be able to access it."_ - only if the `template-tags.php` file actually gets included somewhere before that point.

Comment: It should get included by the `functions.php` of the template, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/68537a8eedb8e9fc594ee10a501e12872e988bcb/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php#L691 - can you verify if that's the case?

Comment: You are correct CBroe. Not sure how it got removed but it was indeed missing from functions.php.

Comment: Please add that as an answer @Junky and accept it (unless there’s still a question, in which case edit the question to clarify :))

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot redeclare twentyfourteen_categorized_blog()" means that your file is trying to declare the same function multiple times. Either the function is defined in two separate files or in two places in the same file.

Comment: This doesn’t add any info/clarity that isn’t already in the question. Note the OP encountered that trying to remedy the function being missing (which likely means it was being declared conditionally or after first use).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by including template_tags.php in functions.php